How can i print something inside a prefect flow which uses prefect-databricks?
I am new to prefect for workflow orchestration. I was exploring it's databricks integration and used it's tutorial example here . I am able to connect to datarbricks instance and I can print the jobs outside the flow i.e. in main with something like this :
if __name__ == "__main__":
   jobs = example_execute_endpoint_flow()
   print(jobs)

but if i try to print this inside the flow itself
@task
def get_job_list():
   databricks_credentials = DatabricksCredentials.load("tnaiv-databricks")
   jobs = jobs_list(
    databricks_credentials,
    limit=5
   )
   print(jobs)
   

it's not prinitng it , it is sending a coroutine. I have tried async await, I have also tried doing this inside a task and return the jobs from there and priniting it in flow. Nothing works. Any suggestions or solutions !

Prefect employee here.
Can you try adding log_prints=True to your task decorator? So that it would look like this:
@task(log_prints=True)
def get_job_list():
   databricks_credentials = DatabricksCredentials.load("tnaiv-databricks")
   jobs = jobs_list(
    databricks_credentials,
    limit=5
   )
   print(jobs)

That should include the print of the jobs to the Prefect UI.

you need to use the await keyword, but since Prefect tasks are asynchronous, this needs to be handled carefully.
here is an example
from prefect import flow, task
from prefect_databricks import DatabricksCredentials, jobs_list

@task
async def get_job_list():
    databricks_credentials = DatabricksCredentials.load("tnaiv-databricks")
    jobs = await jobs_list(databricks_credentials, limit=5)
    return jobs

@flow
def example_execute_endpoint_flow():
    job_list = get_job_list()  # Task to fetch the jobs
    print("Fetching jobs...")  # Prints immediately
    return job_list  # You can print job_list outside of the flow if needed

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Run the flow and fetch jobs
    jobs = example_execute_endpoint_flow()
    print(jobs)  # Print returned jobs

